# Compare multiple dictionaries with exceptions efficiently

Tags: python

I want to compare multiple dictionaries, making sure that all of the keys and values are the same, with some exceptions. I already have a function to compare them, but it takes too long and my script never ends up finishing.

In context, I want to go through a list of files, and merge all of the dictionaries that are the same. Currently my loop looks like this:

```
    out_files = list(itertools.chain(*unpaired_files))
    for items in itertools.product(*new_files):
        if items and self._compare_multiple_dicts_except(all_exceptions, *items):
```

And this is the function to compare the dictionaries:

```
def _compare_multiple_dicts_except(exceptions, *dicts):
    keys = []
    for d in dicts:
        keys.append(
            sorted([key for key in d.keys() if key not in exceptions]))
    if not all(x == keys[0] for x in keys):
        return False
    for key in keys[0]:
        items = [d[key] for d in dicts]
        if not all(x == items[0] for x in items):
            return False
    return True
```

Some example usage:

```
>>> _compare_multiple_dicts_except(['a', 'b'], {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
True
>>> _compare_multiple_dicts_except(['a', 'b'], {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': [4, 5]}, {'c': 4, 'd': [4, 5]})
False
```

I don't know if there is anything I can do to optimize that, or if I need to completely rethink how I merge the dictionaries.

It also must be noted that not everything is hashable, because I have some numpy arrays and lists, so all of the set examples that I've tried don't work.

Comment: I got True from the second test case. Is the problem in the first code block? You're missing an input and import. Please give us a sample like you did in the last "Some example usage" block. Or is the question just to fix _compare_multiple_dicts_except on that second case where I got a different result?

Comment: I changed to remove self because it was originally in a class and both samples work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized that for most of my cases, the keys were different between the dictionaries, so I did some timing tests on variations of my code and blhsing's answers and achieved the following results.

The three variations that I settled on were my original code:

```
# Number 1
def _compare_multiple_dicts_except(exceptions, *dicts):
    keys = []
    for d in dicts:
        keys.append(
            sorted([key for key in d.keys() if key not in exceptions]))
    if not all(x == keys[0] for x in keys):
        return False
    for key in keys[0]:
        items = [d[key] for d in dicts]
        if not all(x == items[0] for x in items):
            return False
    return True
```

blhsing's answer of symmetric difference, with my code to compare the keys first:

```
# Number 2
def _compare_multiple_dicts_except2(exceptions, *dicts):
    first_keys = dicts[0].keys() - exceptions
    for d in dicts[1:]:
        if d.keys() - exceptions != first_keys:
            return False
    first, *dicts = dicts
    reference = freeze(first)
    return all({k for k, _ in reference.symmetric_difference(freeze(d))} <= exceptions for d in dicts)
```

And blhsing's answer of subtracting the exceptions, with my code to compare the keys first.

```
# Number 3
def _compare_multiple_dicts_except3(exceptions, *dicts):
    first_keys = dicts[0].keys() - exceptions
    for d in dicts[1:]:
        if d.keys() - exceptions != first_keys:
            return False
    first, *rest = ({k: d[k] for k in d.keys() - exceptions} for d in dicts)
```

In all of the variations I tried, I found that comparing the keys first with set subtraction was the most efficient.

## Different Keys

I tested the various solutions with dictionaries that have different keys and timed them on 10,000,000 iterations. I created the dictionaries to compare:

```
a = dict.fromkeys("sadjalsdjalskvd")
b = dict.fromkeys("hlkdflkjasdvdae")
```

Variation 1 took 44 seconds on my machine. Variation 2 took 20 seconds on my machine. Variation 3 also took 20 seconds on my machine. This is expected due to 2 and 3 using the same code to compare the keys. However, it is clear that variation 1 is slower.

**Winner:** Variation 2 and 3

## Same Keys

Next I compared when they had the same keys, but one value was changed. For this, I used the following dictionaries and ran it against all my variations. I still ran 10,000,000 iterations.

```
a = dict.fromkeys("sadjalsdjalskvd")
a2 = a.copy()
a2['s'] = 1
```

Variation 1 took 99 seconds on my machine. Variation 2 took 130 seconds. Finally, variation 3 took 61 seconds.

**Winner:** Variation 3

## Overall

Overall, I'm going to use variation 3 in my code, but I'm open to any more optimizations of my code.

Answer (score 3):

The performance of your code can benefit from making `exceptions` a set rather than a list so that each membership test can be done in constant time instead of linear time.

You can also turn each dict into a set of item tuples, so that you can perform symmetric difference on them to make sure the keys to their differences are a subset of the `exceptions` set:

```
def compare_multiple_dicts_except(exceptions, *dicts):
    first, *rest = dicts
    reference = set(first.items())
    return all({k for k, _ in reference.symmetric_difference(d.items())} <= exceptions for d in rest)
```

So that:

```
compare_multiple_dicts_except({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
```

returns: `True`

and that:

```
compare_multiple_dicts_except({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'c': 4, 'd': 4})
```

returns: `False`

If the values of your dicts contain further sub-dicts or sub-lists, as your edit suggests, you can use a recursive function to convert each sub-dict into a frozenset of items, and each sub-list into a frozenset of `collection.Counter` objects:

```
from collections import Counter

def freeze(o):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return frozenset(Counter(map(freeze, o)).items())
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return frozenset((k, freeze(v)) for k, v in o.items())
    return o

def compare_multiple_dicts_except(exceptions, *dicts):
    first, *dicts = dicts
    reference = freeze(first)
    return all({k for k, _ in reference.symmetric_difference(freeze(d))} <= exceptions for d in dicts)
```

So that:

```
compare_multiple_dicts_except({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': [4, 5]}, {'c': 4, 'd': [4, 5]})
```

returns: `False`

Comment: That would be ideal and I've seen some answers about using symmetric difference, but the problem is that my dictionary contains some lists which aren't hashable. I'm going to edit my examples to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach may be to simply rebuild the dicts without the keys in `exceptions` before making comparisons:

```
def compare_multiple_dicts_except(exceptions, *dicts):
    first, *rest = ({k: d[k] for k in d.keys() - exceptions} for d in dicts)
    return all(first == d for d in rest)
```

So that:

```
compare_multiple_dicts_except({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
```

returns: `True`

and that:

```
compare_multiple_dicts_except({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': [4, 5]}, {'c': 4, 'd': [4, 5]})
```

returns: `False`